# Unable to use smtp.gmail.com via telnet

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, telnet

All I did is connected to `smtp.gmail.com` at port `587` via telnet as:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

And typed:

```
EHLO smtp.gmail.com
```

And this was the output I got:

```
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [14.97.86.28]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

Then when I used telnet for the 1st time and typed `AUTH LOGIN`, I got something like:

```
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
```

I successfully sent a mail for the 1st time. And exited my `telnet` program with a `QUIT` command.

BUT from the 2nd time and onwards, whenever I type `AUTH LOGIN`, all I get is:

```
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. x79sm16871877pfi.47 - gsmtp
```

Even after this when I type:

```
STARTTLS
```

I get:

```
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

But after that if I give any other command, my connection is automatically closed and all I get is this:

```
FConnection closed by foreign host.
```

What have I messed up? I need to get this thing working. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using OAuth2 (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) Google classify your access as an access from a less secure app.
If you want to enable mail sending from telnet you can enable less secure app into your gmail account (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: I don't get it. Google is closing the connection before I can even authenticate. How can it know then that I have this setting on or off?

Comment: You have to log into your google account via browser and then enable less secure app (see the second link in my answer)

Comment: well it was just that I was using telnet and then it was not encrypted communication as soon as you start tls, you have to use ```openssl s_client -debug -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp-relay.gmail.com:587```. (I was getting dropped before I could even indicate to google which was my email address, so how could google now that I had this setting on/off?)